# Divide the whole screen into four equal parts

Tags: react-native, webview, flexbox, prompt, touchableopacity

I want to divide the whole screen into 4 equal parts each having a clickable action and onclick a prompt should appear with a textbox and an okay button on pressing it I need to render a webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing this in react-native then use below code. This will divide screens in four parts and with `TouchableOpacity` you can use click events reflection otherwise you can use simple `View`.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
      onPress={() => {  }} // Action
    >
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
      onPress={() => {  }} // Action
    >
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
      onPress={() => {  }} // Action
    >
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}
      onPress={() => {  }} // Action
    >
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
</View>
```

Yes, you can use common styling and components but for now I use separate So, you can easily edit and test.

Comment: How to add a prompt on clicking where he can input a text and store it and also navigate to a new screen?

Comment: You mean you want to open a dialog with input text area and perform a event after enter text ( By that event user can save text and switch to next screen)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vw`(viewport width) and `vh` (viewport height), and assign to all of your items

```
width: "50vw",
height: "50vh"
```

Comment: I want to achieve it using flex ? How do I do that?

Comment: then just use a parent `View` with flex 1, and children with flex 0.5. wrap them in views, to use first flex direction column then row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
     <View style={{flex: 1}}> </View>
     <View style={{flex: 1}}> </View>

</View>
```